# Magento product import through admin doesn't properly import the product's category

Tags: magento, import, categories, product

Why can't I upload a product in Magento, so that product ends up in another category? I tried putting values from both fields (entity_id and value) into CSV from the database table catalog_category_entity_varchar, and the category stays the same. I have these fields in the CSV:
sku _store  _attribute_set  type    category_ids    _root_category  _product_websites   activation_information  color   computer_manufacturers  contrast_ratio  cost    country_of_manufacture  country_orgin   cpu_speed   created_at  custom_design   custom_design_from  custom_design_to    custom_layout_update    description dimension   finish  gallery gender  gift_message_available  harddrive_speed hardrive    has_options image   image_label in_depth    manufacturer    max_resolution  media_gallery   megapixels  memory  meta_description    meta_keyword    meta_title  minimal_price   model   msrp    msrp_display_actual_price_type  msrp_enabled    name    news_from_date  news_to_date    options_container   page_layout price   processor   ram_size    required_options    response_time   room    screensize  shape   shirt_size  shoe_size   shoe_type   short_description   small_image small_image_label   special_from_date   special_price   special_to_date status  tax_class_id    thumbnail   thumbnail_label updated_at  url_key url_path    visibility  weight  qty min_qty use_config_min_qty  is_qty_decimal  backorders  use_config_backorders   min_sale_qty    use_config_min_sale_qty max_sale_qty    use_config_max_sale_qty is_in_stock notify_stock_qty    use_config_notify_stock_qty manage_stock    use_config_manage_stock stock_status_changed_auto   use_config_qty_increments   qty_increments  use_config_enable_qty_inc   enable_qty_increments   is_decimal_divided  _links_related_sku  _links_related_position _links_crosssell_sku    _links_crosssell_position   _links_upsell_sku   _links_upsell_position  _associated_sku _associated_default_qty _associated_position    _tier_price_website _tier_price_customer_group  _tier_price_qty _tier_price_price   _group_price_website    _group_price_customer_group _group_price_price  _media_attribute_id _media_image    _media_lable    _media_position _media_is_disabled  _super_products_sku _super_attribute_code   _super_attribute_option _super_attribute_price_corr

and editing , for example, product name (name field in the above list) works without problems.
I am using the admin->system->import->Products->replace existing complex data functionality to import.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the csv file through **System->Import/Export->Dataflow -Profiles->Import All Products** ? You can try exporting the products through **System->Import/Export->Dataflow -Profiles->Export All Products** and create a sample csv file from exported csv file and import it.

Comment: This only produces entry errors when I check this file (prior to importing it back):
    Invalid value for 'status' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
    Invalid value for 'tax_class_id' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
    Invalid value for 'visibility' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
    Invalid value for 'gift_message_available' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 1etc, etc...

Comment: Have you modified the following fields before importing it back ? sku, name, url_key, url_path ? Status should be **Enabled**. you can set tax_class_id as **None**

Comment: which following fields? The exported fields are the same except for product name, which I modified by one letter. SPecificcaly, I changed the category_ids for one product to be 30 instead of 29.

Comment: also set gift_message_available as **No**.

Comment: I set it to No and the message still stays (regarding the gift message available)

Comment: sorry, the question was still about importing/exporting using technique I described above. I need this urgently, my client doesn't know any other way of doing the import but with the way I described above.

"I am using the admin->system->import->Products->replace existing complex data functionality to import."

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic: if still it doesn't work, maybe you would like to try [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). It is also used to import products in bulk using csv files.

Comment: thanks @akt . I will maybe try that, but I really need this, and not any other way.